# Calling a specific function

Tags: python, function, user-input

I am trying to build a small temperature converter. I was wondering how can I account for the user input in the beginning and run either of the two functions below not both and in order?

Should I use a while() loop in the beginning?

Thanks for the help.

```
user_input = input("This is a temperature converter. What do you want to convert:")

def convert_f():
    if user_input == "Celsius" or "C":
        print("To convert a temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit. ")
        celsius = input("Celsius: ")
        convert_to_fahrenheit = float(celsius) * 9 / 5 + 3
        print(str(celsius), "degrees Celsius",  "is", float(convert_to_fahrenheit) , "degrees Fahrenheit")
convert_f()

def convert_c():
    if user_input == "Fahrenheit" or "F":
        print ("To convert a temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius:")
        fahrenheit = input("Fahrenheit: ")
        convert_to_celsius: (float(fahrenheit) -32 * (5/9))
        print(str(fahrenheit), "degrees Fahrenheit", "is", float(convert_to_celsius), "degrees Celsius")
convert()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check with an `if` in the `while` loop for the input. When you got something else than "C" or "F" (like the user pressed simply Enter) you can exit (break the loop).

```
def convert_f():
    print("To convert a temperature from Celsius to Fahrenheit. ")
    celsius = input("Celsius: ")
    convert_to_fahrenheit = float(celsius) * 9 / 5 + 3
    print(str(celsius), "degrees Celsius", "is", float(convert_to_fahrenheit), "degrees Fahrenheit")


def convert_c():
    print("To convert a temperature from Fahrenheit to Celsius:")
    fahrenheit = input("Fahrenheit: ")
    convert_to_celsius = (float(fahrenheit) - 32 * (5 / 9))
    print(str(fahrenheit), "degrees Fahrenheit", "is", float(convert_to_celsius), "degrees Celsius")


while True:
    user_input = input("This is a temperature converter. What do you want to convert:")
    if user_input == "Celsius" or user_input == "C":
        convert_f()
    elif user_input == "Fahrenheit" or user_input == "F":
        convert_c()
    else:
        print("Invalid input. Exit.")
        break
```

Comment: Thank you. If I run this it still starts of with the first function def convert_f regardless of user input. 

And if I put the while loop at the top I get the error that both functions are not defined yet. So I am still kind of lost.

Comment: Are you sure you copied my code correctly? Or do you have an additional `convert_f()` call somewhere? Otherwise the function would not be executed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. It works perfectly for Celsius but if I put in F or Fahrenheit it still calls the first function.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not possible. Checkout [this Repl.it](https://replit.com/@sveneberth/temperature-converter#main.py).

Comment: Apologies, I am beginner and I am using Pycharm as IDE so if I run something it runs the last scratch file not the most recent. It works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would restructure this code to reduce repetition.

IMO the main logic of the application should be separated from the I/O sections (printing and asking for input).

Make some simple methods to do the transformations, and simple methods to do the inputs. Making simple methods will also allow you to unit test each one of them separately!

```
def convert_c_to_f(celsius):
    return (celsius * (9 / 5)) + 32

def convert_f_to_c(fahrenheit):
    return (fahrenheit - 32) * (5 / 9)

def ask_calc_type():
    while True:
        user_input = input(
            "This is a temperature converter. "
            "What do you want to convert:"
        )
        if user_input in ("Celsius", "C"):
            return "Celsius", "Fahrenheit"
        elif user_input in ("Fahrenheit" or "F"):
            return "Fahrenheit", "Celsius"
        else:
            print("Invalid choice, try again.")

def ask_number(from_type):
    while True:
        number = input(from_type + ":")
        try:
            return float(number)
        except:
            print("Invalid number, try again.")
```

Now you can put this all together:

```
from_type, to_type = ask_calc_type()
request = ask_number(from_type)
if from_type == "Fahrenheit":
    response = convert_f_to_c(request)
else:
    response = convert_c_to_f(request)
print(f"{request} degrees {from_type} is {response} degrees {to_type}")
```